# lxml.etree not returning proper xpath value

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I have an xml string like this

```
<description> asdasdasd <a> Item1 </a><a> Price </a></description>
```

i'm using lxml.etree as follows:

```
import lxml.etree as le
doc=le.fromstring("<description>asdasdasd <a>Item1</a> <a>Price</a> </description>")
desc = doc.xpath("//description")[0]
print desc.text
```

But `desc.text` is returning only **asdasdasd**. I was expecting `asdasdasd Item1 Price`. Is there any issue with my codes?

Comment: Please see if any of the answers deserves to be accepted to resolve the topic. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
print desc.text + ' '.join(child.text for child in desc)
```

prints:

```
asdasdasd Item1 Price
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `descendant-or-self` xpath trick:

```
desc = doc.xpath("//description/descendant-or-self::*")
print ' '.join(child.text for child in desc)
```

prints:

```
asdasdasd  Item1 Price
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to see that as a tree (that's why `lxml.etree`)

An xml node can, by definition, have a text and some attributes and other nodes inside (see [this](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_nodes.asp))

```
|--> description
      |--> a
      |--> a
```

Maybe this helps understand:

```
import lxml.etree as le
doc=le.fromstring("<description>asdasdasd <a>Item1</a> <a>Price</a> </description>")
desc = doc.xpath("//description")[0]
print desc.text
for child in desc:
  print child.text
```

That outputs:

```
asdasdasd 
Item1
Price
```

The idea behind XML is to try to model instances (more or less). In your case, you have a `description` object with two `a` objects inside it (could be a list, for instance)